# One node isn't catch with for each loop JS

Tags: javascript, loops, addeventlistener

I have some issue with a for each loop and I don't understand what's happenned.
I have 6 cards (all puts with JS, there is no html).
I try to catch all cards IDs in the url when I click on them with a for each loop.
All works good...for 5 cards ! No matter what I do, the 6th cards doesn't works.

When I look at the console, there is 6 nodes in the loop but the first is empty, I think it is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it !!!
The NodeList(5) have 5 cards in place of 6 et the first is empty...

What the console.log show in browsers:

```
NodeList []
NodeList [ article#243.cardsLink]
NodeList [ article#243.cardsLink, article#930.cardsLink]
NodeList(3) [ article#243.cardsLink, article#930.cardsLink, article#82.cardsLink]
NodeList(4) [ article#243.cardsLink, article#930.cardsLink, article#82.cardsLink, article#527.cardsLink]
NodeList(5) [ article#243.cardsLink, article#930.cardsLink, article#82.cardsLink, article#527.cardsLink, article#925.cardsLink ]
```

My loop :

```js
let cardsLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.cardsLink')
console.log(cardsLinks);
cardsLinks.forEach((cardsLinked)=>cardsLinked.addEventListener("click", ()=> { window.location = `photographer.html?id=${cardsLink.id}`}));
```

Html put with JS :

```html
<article id="243" class="cardsLink"></article>
<article id="930" class="cardsLink"></article>
<article id="82" class="cardsLink"></article>
<article id="527" class="cardsLink"></article>
<article id="925" class="cardsLink"></article>
<article id="195" class="cardsLink"></article>
```

Anyone have a advice ?

Thanks a lot.

Gilles

Comment: The value of `window.location` should be a URL. Why are you assigning a JS assignment statement?

Comment: Where is that console output coming from? `console.log(cardLinks)` isn't inside the `forEach()` loop.

Comment: The iteration variable is `cardsLinked`, why are you using `cardsLink.id`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: How did you get those logs from the part after you wrote `the console:` ?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a loop that creates the nodes, and you're logging before you create each node instead of after.

Comment: Thank you, it's difficulte for me to explain this problem, I'm new to JS and this is an exercice. I edited some things to be a little more accurate.
I will look at this option, the loop before the loop !

Comment: impossible to determine your problem with the information provided. If the article tags are dynamic, then your issue resides with that code and when you are binding the events. But in the end with event delegation,  you would not need any loop.

Comment: Thank you all, I solved my problem ! 
It was a loop in a loop..., I moved my function in an other place and it works well !